# Detect native video call in android - detect 3G-324M video call

Tags: android, video, call, native

I want to know how to detect an incoming Video call on android device? 
Actually there are lots of documentation on detecting incoming phone calls but I couldn't find any information on detecting incoming native video calls in android?

So may you let me know on this?